# The best way to set global instance in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class of Publish:

```ruby
class Publish
  def initialize(app_id, secret_key)
    @app_id = app_id
    @secret_key = secret_key
  end

  def publish(source_file, target_link)
    # ...
  end
end
```

and I want a global instance variable of Publish, so I do some thing in initializer:

```ruby
Publish.class_eval do
  class_attribute :instance
end

Publish.instance = Publish.new(Settings.app_id, Settings.secret_key)
```

So I could retrieve the instance in everywhere:

```ruby
Publish.instance.publish(source_file, target_link)
```

However, If I change the code of Publish, It will throw a error `undefined method 'instance' of Publish` because of auto-reload.

Answer (score 1):

Put the instance creation/assignment inside a `to_prepare` block. That way it'll be created just once in production, but any time the application is reloaded in development mode.

```
Rails.application.config.to_prepare do
  Publish.instance = Publish.new(Settings.app_id, Settings.secret_key)
end
```

(I'd move the `class_attribute` into the class definition -- but you could put that in the `to_prepare` too if you like.)

Comment: Maybe it is the best choice.